# In Magento2, how to get checked checkboxes values in uicomponent grid in frontend?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-form, grid-layout

I have added grid using uicomponent in Magento 2 frontend, to list related products. grid is showing fine but now i want to get checked checkboxes values (in any hidden input if possible) to send that with form data.

Screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code?